# How to Style HTML Text with Custom CSS Class

Tags: html, css

I have created some CSS classes that simply declare certain hex colors that will be used in my web app. In HTML I am trying to apply these colors to specific text. For some reason I am having trouble getting the styles to be applied.

CSS

```
.custom-orange-color {
  color: #F58B30;
}

.custom-pink-color {
  color: #ED178F;
}
```

HTML

```
<p>This is the custom <style class="custom-orange-color">orange</style> color and this is the custom <style class="custom-pink-color">pink</style> color.</p>
```

In fact when I use this, the text within the `style` tags disappears all together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misusing the css classes. Instead of `<style>` tags use `<span>`. Style tags are used to put css in it, not use classes or whatever css rules.

> The span tag is used to group inline-elements in a document.
>
> The span tag provides no visual change by itself.
>
> The span tag provides a way to add a hook to a part of a text or a
>   part of a document.

In your case you can assign the desired colors by assigning the correct class to corresponding span element. It would be something like this:

```css
.custom-orange-color {
  color: #F58B30;
}

.custom-pink-color {
  color: #ED178F;
}
```

```html
<p>This is the custom <span class="custom-orange-color">orange</span> color and this is the custom <span class="custom-pink-color">pink</span> color.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<style>` element is designed to hold **a stylesheet**. It is not designed to hold **content**.

The `<body>` of your document should contain text and the HTML elements which best describe the semantics of that text.

The `<style>` element should appear in the `<head>` and contain **only** CSS.

Replace `<style class="custom-orange-color">` which something that best describes what it is you want to convey by making the text orange. For example:

```
<em>
```

Then write CSS for it.

```css
em {
  color: #F58B30;
  font-style: normal;
}

strong {
  color: #ED178F;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<p>This is the <em>emphasised</em> color and this is the <strong>strongly emphasised</strong> color.</p>
```

Add HTML classes (CSS has class selectors, other kinds of selector, rules, rulesets and various other features, but not classes) only if you need them.

Your syntax for a class selector was correct (although the names were poorly chosen: They should describe meaning not presentation), it was the HTML that was wrong. This would have been picked up if you had used [a validator](http://validator.w3.org/nu/).

Answer (score -1):

Here is working code for you. You need to use HTML tags, in order to have the style render for you.  tag is used to define the CSS for your HTML. It basically holds a stylesheet and not the content.

```css
.custom-orange-color {
  color: #F58B30;
}

.custom-pink-color {
  color: #ED178F;
}
```

```html
<p>This is the custom <span class="custom-orange-color">orange</span> color and this is the custom <span class="custom-pink-color">pink</span> color.</p>
```